# Change background randomly when the page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, random

I have 10 image files in a folder ( images ) named from 1.jpg to 10.jpg

What I want to do is to change the background randomly every time the page is refreshed

This is what I have tried so far :

```
<body background='<?php echo 'images/'.rand(1,6).'.jpg' ?>'>
```

This doesn't work .

Can anybody tell me how to do this using php, please ?

Comment: I can do this with jquery if you are interested?

Comment: Yes I am interested if your code changes the background randomly when the page is refreshed . Thank you

Comment: I prefer php . But let's see

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your PHP script. Verify that your images directory is in the same directory as the PHP file. Can you open the images directly in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
var min = 1;
var max = 6;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
$("body").css("background-image","url(images/"+random+".jpg")
}):
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First create an array of images:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
```

Then, set a random image as the background image:

```
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'});
```